# create table using execute sql task in ssis failed to parse

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to create a table in excel sheet based on variable. When I execute the  SQL Task in control flow it gives me an error

> "[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "Create Table'XXX'
>   ('SEQ_ID' lo..." failed with the following error: "Syntax error in
>   CREATE TABLE statement.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the
>   query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set
>   correctly, or connection not established correctly".

The variable that I used is

```
    "Create Table'"+(DT_STR,20,1252) @[User::SALES]+ "'           ('SEQ_ID' long
      ,'LEGACY_CUSTOMER_ID' longtext
      ,'NAME' longtext

      ,'LEGACY_DB' longtext
       ,'ADDRESS_STREET' longtext
       ,'ADDRESS_CITY' longtext
       ,'ADDRESS_STATE' longtext
       ,'ADDRESS_COUNTY' longtext
       ,'ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE' longtext

      ,'SALES_PERSON' longtext
  )"
```

Below is the image of the execute sql task 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

- using ` instead of '
- using NVARCHAR(255) instead of longtext
- check spaces between words

Your variable should look like

```
"Create Table `" + (DT_STR,20,1252) @[User::SALES] + "`           
(`SEQ_ID` INTEGER
  ,`LEGACY_CUSTOMER_ID` NVARCHAR(255)
  ,`NAME` NVARCHAR(255)
  ,`LEGACY_DB` NVARCHAR(255)
   ,`ADDRESS_STREET` NVARCHAR(255)
   ,`ADDRESS_CITY` NVARCHAR(255)
   ,`ADDRESS_STATE` NVARCHAR(255)
   ,`ADDRESS_COUNTY` NVARCHAR(255)
   ,`ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE` NVARCHAR(255)
   ,`SALES_PERSON` NVARCHAR(255)
 )"
```

You can read the example provided in this link

- https://www.google.com.lb/amp/s/dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/amp/